# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'SCTrack'

Tags: ios, core-data

Hate to ask this question because there seems to be a bunch of other similar ones and but I still can't see what is wrong with mine after going through most of the answers.

I have two VCs, VC1 contains a list of songs fetched from a music service.  VC2 contains a list of songs picked from VC1; VC2 is basically a playlist.

I've set up my entity name and class to match: SCTrack.  Here is my SCTrack.h:

```
@interface SCTrack : NSManagedObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* stream_url;
```

SCTrack.m:

```
#import "SCTrack.h"
@implementation SCTrack

@dynamic title;
@dynamic stream_url;

-(instancetype) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) SCTrackDict {
self = [self init];
if (self) {
    self.title = SCTrackDict[@"title"];
    self.stream_url = SCTrackDict[@"stream_url"];

}
return self;
}

+(NSMutableArray *) parseJSONData: (NSData *) JSONData {
NSError* error;
NSMutableArray* SCTrackArray = [NSMutableArray new];

NSArray *JSONArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:0 error: &error];
if ([JSONArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary* trackDict in JSONArray) {
        SCTrack* trackObject = [[SCTrack alloc]initWithDictionary:trackDict];
        [SCTrackArray addObject:trackObject];
    }
}
return SCTrackArray;
}

@end
```

My AppDelegate.m

```
 UITabBarController* tabBar = (UITabBarController*) self.window.rootViewController;
SCTrackListVC *SCVC = (SCTrackListVC*) [[tabBar viewControllers]objectAtIndex:2];

SCVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
return YES;
```

In my VC1.m

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
self.selectedTrack = self.SCTrackList[indexPath.row];
self.selectedTrackRow = indexPath.row;

self.selectedTrack = [[SCTrack alloc]initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SCTrack" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSError* error;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
}

//This is the other way I tried it _selectedTrack = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SCTrack" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

In my VC2.m

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*) fetchedResultController {
if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *SCTrackEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SCTrack" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:SCTrackEntity];



//    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
//    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];

_fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

_fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultController;
}
```

This is the error I get: 
    CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'SCTrack'

Very new to Core Data.  Been at this for a few hours now.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initialiser for NSManaged Object is **initWithEntity: insertIntoManagedObjectContext:**.
Change

```
SCTrack* trackObject = [[SCTrack alloc]initWithDictionary:trackDict];
```

to

```
SCTrack *trackObject = [[SCTrack alloc]initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks.  But won't this save every SCTrack that would be populated in VC1?  I just want to save the SCTracks that are added to VC2 only, though.

Comment: Yes it will. If you don't want to save an NSManaged object, why are you initialising it in first place?

Comment: I'm initializing it to display on VC1.  I only want to pick a few from there (VC1) to save into VC2 as a playlist.  I only want the playlist to persist.  I think I'm finding a possible solution by create a separate CoreData entity class (calling it SCCoreDataTrack) to represent SCTrack for my VC2...But you definitely gave me a huge clue.

Comment: If you do not want to save then you can populate VC1 using trackDict. Then filter from dictionary and save objects you want to save.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to iOS...Could you elaborate a little on filtering?

Comment: For example you have 10 dictionary objects and you want to get only those with specific attributes, run a loop on all dictionary objects and get the desired objects in an array.